# Duplicate Zip entry MultiDex.class

Tags: android, proguard, android-multidex

I have an android app that just went over the method limit so I tried enabling multidex. Once I do it I get the following error:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForProdDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/user/dev/myapp/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/prod/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/Users/user/dev/myapp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/prod/debug/65.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [65.jar:android/support/multidex/MultiDex.class]))
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/user/dev/myapp/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/prod/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/Users/user/dev/myapp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/prod/debug/65.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [65.jar:android/support/multidex/MultiDex.class]))
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:187)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:79)
    at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:427)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:175)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:61)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.shrinkWithProguard(MainDexListTransform.java:232)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.transform(MainDexListTransform.java:184)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [/Users/user/dev/myapp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/prod/debug/65.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [65.jar:android/support/multidex/MultiDex.class])
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:188)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:158)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:176)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [65.jar:android/support/multidex/MultiDex.class]
    at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:138)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
    at proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:184)
    ... 50 more
```

This is my gradle build file:

```
def versionMajor = 1
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 0 // bump for dogfood builds, public betas, etc.


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // Use experimental kapt implementation

apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'

def gitSha() {
    def p = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir)
    p.waitFor()
    if (p.exitValue() != 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException(p.errorStream.text)
    }

    return p.text.trim()
}

def gitTimestamp() {
    def p = 'git log -n 1 --format=%at'.execute([], rootDir)
    p.waitFor()
    if (p.exitValue() != 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException(p.errorStream.text)
    }

    return p.text.trim()
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/ttymsd/maven"
    }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion versions.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion versions.buildTools

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tv.myapp"

        minSdkVersion versions.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion versions.targetSdk

        buildConfigField 'String', 'GIT_SHA', "\"${gitSha()}\""
        buildConfigField 'long', 'GIT_TIMESTAMP', "${gitTimestamp()}L"

        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/java'
    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "environment"

    productFlavors {
        prod {
            dimension "environment"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FABRIC', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'ENV', '"PRODUCTION"'
            applicationId = "tv.myapp"
        }

        beta {
            dimension "environment"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FABRIC', 'true'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'ENV', '"PRODUCTION"'
            applicationId = "tv.myapp.beta"
        }

        dev {
            dimension "environment"
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'FABRIC', 'false'
            buildConfigField "String", "ENV", '"STAGING"'
            applicationId = "tv.myapp.dev"
        }

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        textReport true
        textOutput 'stdout'
        lintConfig rootProject.file('lint.xml')
        // We run a full lint analysis as build part in CI, so skip vital checks for assemble tasks.
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }


    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    dependencies {

        //Kotlin
        implementation deps.kotlin.core
        implementation deps.kotlin.reflect

        //UI
        implementation deps.sectionedRecyclerview
        implementation deps.support.constraint
        implementation deps.support.cardview

        //Support
        implementation deps.support.appCompat
        implementation(deps.support.design) {
            exclude group: "com.android.support", module: 'multidex'
        }
        implementation deps.support.v4
        implementation deps.support.fragment
        implementation deps.support.recyclerView
        implementation deps.support.vector

        //Cast
        implementation deps.cast.mediarouter
        implementation deps.cast.playServices

        //Net
        implementation deps.retrofit.core
        implementation deps.retrofit.gson
        implementation deps.retrofit.rxjava

        implementation deps.okhttp.core
        implementation deps.okhttp.urlConnection
        implementation deps.okhttp.logger

        implementation deps.picasso

        //Logging
        compile deps.timber

        //Gson
        implementation deps.gson

        //Rx
        implementation deps.rx.core
        implementation deps.rx.android
        implementation deps.rx.kotlin
        implementation deps.rx.rxDelay

        // DEPENDENCY INJECTION LIBRARIES
        kapt deps.dagger.compiler
        implementation deps.dagger.runtime

        // Databinding
        kapt deps.databinding

        implementation deps.exoplayer

        //Test
        testImplementation deps.junit
        testImplementation deps.espresso.core
        testImplementation deps.espresso.contrib


        implementation deps.multidex
    }
}
```

And this is the dependency definition:

```
ext.versions = [
            'buildTools'    : '26.0.2',
            'minSdk'        : 17,
            'targetSdk'     : 26,
            'compileSdk'    : 26,
            'supportLibrary': '26.0.0',

            'dagger'        : '2.9',
            //Net
            'okHttp'        : '3.4.2',
            'retrofit'      : '2.3.0',
            'retrorx'       : '1.0.0',

            'gson'          : '2.4',
            'picasso'       : '2.5.2',

            //Rx
            'rxjava'        : '2.1.0',
            'rxandroid'     : '2.0.1',
            'rxkotlin'      : '2.1.0',
            'rxpreferences' : '1.0.2',

            //App dependencies
            'junit'         : '4.12',
            'espresso'      : '2.2.2',

            //UI
            'coordinator'   : '0.3.3',
            'playServices'  : '10.2.0',

            'kotlin'        : '1.1.3-2',

    ]

    ext.deps = [
            'support'              : [
                    'annotations' : "com.android.support:support-annotations:${versions.supportLibrary}",
                    'v4'          : "com.android.support:support-v4:${versions.supportLibrary}",
                    'appCompat'   : "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${versions.supportLibrary}",
                    'design'      : "com.android.support:design:${versions.supportLibrary}",
                    'recyclerView': "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${versions.supportLibrary}",
                    'fragment'    : "com.android.support:support-fragment:${versions.supportLibrary}",
                    'vector'      : "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:${versions.supportLibrary}",
                    'cardview'    : "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${versions.supportLibrary}",
                    'constraint'  : "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2",

            ],
            'dagger'               : [
                    'compiler': "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${versions.dagger}",
                    'runtime' : "com.google.dagger:dagger:${versions.dagger}",
            ],
            'okhttp'               : [
                    'core'         : "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${versions.okHttp}",
                    'logger'       : "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${versions.okHttp}",
                    'urlConnection': "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:${versions.okHttp}"
            ],
            'retrofit'             : [
                    'core'  : "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${versions.retrofit}",
                    'mock'  : "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:${versions.retrofit}",
                    'gson'  : "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${versions.retrofit}",
                    'rxjava': "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:${versions.retrorx}",
            ],
            'rx'                   : [
                    'core'       : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${versions.rxjava}",
                    'android'    : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${versions.rxandroid}",
                    'preferences': "com.f2prateek.rx.preferences:rx-preferences:${versions.rxpreferences}",
                    'kotlin'     : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:${versions.rxkotlin}",
                    'rxDelay'    : 'com.github.Plastix.RxDelay:rx2:0.5.0',
            ],
            'cast'                 : [
                    'mediarouter' : "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:${versions.supportLibrary}",
                    'playServices': 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.2.1',
            ],
            'kotlin'               : [
                    'core'  : "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:${versions.kotlin}",
                    'reflect': "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${versions.kotlin}"
            ],

            'sectionedRecyclerview': 'com.afollestad:sectioned-recyclerview:0.5.0',
            'targetTooltip'        : 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.15',

            'picasso'              : "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:${versions.picasso}",
            'timber'               : 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.2',
            'gson'                 : "com.google.code.gson:gson:${versions.gson}",
            'databinding'          : "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version",
            'exoplayer'            : 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.1',
            'junit'                : "junit:junit:${versions.junit}",

            'espresso'             : [
                    'core'   : "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:${versions.espresso}",
                    'contrib': "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:${versions.espresso}",
            ],
            'multidex': "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2"
    ]
```

Project is being developed in Kotlin, with Android Studio 3.0, gradle plugin 3.0.0.

I tried not explicitly putting the dependency on the dependencies section, I tried excluding from "design" (which as far as I could see was the only dependency transitively bringing multidex), I tried with multidex 1.0.1, 1.0.2 but nothing seems to work.

I've ran out of ideas. If I switch to the "dev" flavor, mysteriously it works.

Comment: i faced this issues its because you are using two or more libs which are compiled with a different version of multidex class.

Comment: @AbuQauod I checked with app:dependencies and only support-design is using multidex, and I tried excluding that (as you can see in my build.gradle)

Comment: Have you figured out anything? I have run into the same issue and I can't seem to find out what the heck is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to import Multidex by itself.  Multidex is included in `android.support`, and it may be clashing with the multidex that you are trying to import yourself.  Try to remove that line and see if it works.

Also, the reason the "build flavors" are working is due to the fact that your release build is pointing at the proguard file to follow.  I'm curious if your proguard file has `-keep class android.support.*`, which would be the reason why multidex is failing on you.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

We had an absolute facepalm-worthy cause for this exact same problem:

```
debugImplementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2"
```

And there was a `release` build flavor specific implementation for `android.support.multidex.MultiDex` in our project with the packages and everything, which was an empty stub (do nothing).

So removing the offending class fixed the build.

```
implementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I ran into this issue and below is the Exception message that I got

```
(Duplicate zip entry [multidex.jar:android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V14.class]))
```

I don't know the context of this issue, but the root cause of this issue was

1. Adding maven dependency from google repo (the prompts that we get during gradle sync for adding maven dependency)

When removed and tried building the APK, it worked !

! Pretty hacky solution !